# Replace text in span tag with text from anchor tag - drop down menu

Tags: jquery

I have got a dropdown menu in which I am trying to get the text in the anchor tags to dynamically change the text inside the span tag upon clicking the individual button. At the moment I am able to do it, but as you can see from the code below, the script will easily become too long. Hence, I believe that there is a simpler way to do it using the classes, though I am struggling to successfully do it.

```js
$(".menu__item").click(function() {
  var btnId = $(this).attr('data-btnId');
  $(".selecBox").text('Example');
  $('.menu').removeClass('-is--open');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <a class="dropdown -spacing--dense" role="button" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <span class="selecBox">Arizona</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
  <div class="menu -theme--light -position--below -align--left">
    <a class="menu__item" role="button" aria-pressed="true" data-btnId="btn1">Arizona</a>
    <a class="menu__item" role="button" aria-pressed="true" data-btnId="btn2">California</a>
    <a class="menu__item" role="button" aria-pressed="true" data-btnId="btn3">Colorado</a>
    <a class="menu__item" role="button" aria-pressed="true" data-btnId="btn4">Delaware</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the text from the anchor with `$(this).text()`

```js
$(".menu__item").click(function() {
  var btnId = $(this).attr('data-btnId');
  $(".selecBox").text($(this).text());
  $('.menu').removeClass('-is--open');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <a class="dropdown -spacing--dense" role="button" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <span class="selecBox">Arizona</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
  <div class="menu -theme--light -position--below -align--left">
    <a class="menu__item" role="button" aria-pressed="true" data-btnId="btn1">Arizona</a>
    <a class="menu__item" role="button" aria-pressed="true" data-btnId="btn2">California</a>
    <a class="menu__item" role="button" aria-pressed="true" data-btnId="btn3">Colorado</a>
    <a class="menu__item" role="button" aria-pressed="true" data-btnId="btn4">Delaware</a>
  </div>
</div>
```